# Isekai manga where the MC uses a sword, even though he's stronger in magic, and is personally hired by a wealthy businesswoman

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai

The story is an isekai fantasy manga, mostly in black and white, and I recall it following video game logic. I don't remember if it's a reincarnation manga. It might be a light novel adaptation.

The main character (MC) is transported to a fantasy world, and is stuck using a sword. This may have been because he doesn't have an appropriate magical staff, or wants to hide his magic proficiency. Despite using a sword, he is an expert swordsman by the world's standards.

Near the very start of the manga, I remember him applying to a guild, and was tested with a 1v1 sword fight, with him winning and passing. Everyone's impression of him was favorable.

He later went on a boat, encountering two women who needed help with creating a potion, requiring a rare ingredient. The MC coincidentally had the ingredient, and helped them out, which they were grateful for. Later, the boat was attacked by a giant sea-monster (kraken or serpent?). The protagonist saved the boat with only his sword, and everyone on-board is amazed by his skill. One of the women he helped out earlier approached him and revealed that she was the owner of a large business, and scouted him. She gave him a special card to show he was affiliated with her business.

Sometime after the MC gets off the boat, he goes to a tavern and notices a server getting harassed by a group of rowdy men. The MC confronts them, and they get scared off when he unknowingly showed his card to pay for his meal. It was revealed the the card indicated that he was a high profile person of one of the fantasy world's most influential companies/businesses.

The MC meets up with the business owner again, and she gives him a task of eradicating some pests that were ruining the business' farms (which I remember to be giant moles). The MC goes to the farm, and kills dozens of moles, much to the surprise of the farm owner, as she thought there was only one. When the MC meets back up with the business owner, she is surprised it only took him one day to finish the task, even joking if he forgot something. She then negotiated a personal contract with him to do tasks for her business.

Some of the details may be wrong, but I distinctly remember the sequence of events being correct.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: @LogicDictates mostly black and white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ***[The Unrivaled Reincarnated Sage of Another World: The Strongest in Another World Through Game Knowledges](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/972j7k7/isekai-kenja-no-tensei-musou-game-no-chishiki-de-isekai-saikyou)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Due to an unfortunate death, a young man reincarnates under the name Eld in a world very similar to the VRMMO that he played before his passing. However, this world he found himself in didn't even know what basic skills were! As the only person with knowledge beyond the populace, Eld sets off on a journey as a level 1 novice to job change into the strongest class in the world, Sage!

A young Japanese man dies from a heart condition and is reincarnated as Eldo, the son of a noble in the world of a video game he was a highly-ranked player in.  He starts out with the job of 'Novice' -- a job for people who don't have a proper job yet -- and his only weapon initially is a sword. He wants the most powerful job of 'Sage,' but must visit a special cathedral in the Royal Capital to change jobs to that, and will then need a staff to optimise his magic.

He applies for membership at an adventurers' guild, thinking that they'll probably know the best way to get to the capital, but is told that he'll need to pass an exam. He's given several options, but they all require job-related skills, and as a Novice, the only exam he thinks he stands a chance at passing is a one-on-one duel with a swordsman. He expect to lose, due to his Level 1 stats, but ends up winning by using his pre-existing knowledge of the game's mechanics to anticipate and avoid his opponent's opening strike, then counter with a critical hit.

He then boards a ship, where he helps two women brew a potion by adding a rare ingredient that was missing. One of the women, named Mina Maxia, rewards him with a gold card which is a "proof of trust" from her company, the Maxia Company. Eldo also helps the ship fight off an attack from a sea dragon.

After leaving the ship, he enters a bar and orders a meal, but is approached by an unruly man who demands that he give up his seat. When he refuses to move, the man draws a sword and swings it at him, but exploiting his knowledge of the game again, Eldo uses a fork to deflect the strike with a critical counter, which knocks the sword from the man's hands. He then subdues the man by stepping behind him and grabbing his arms.

The man is outraged and threatens to make Eldo's life a living hell, since he has a bronze card from the Zainis Company, which he seems to think makes him a bigshot. The man is shocked, though, when Eldo produces his gold card from the Maxia Company and gets down on his knees and begs for forgiveness.

Eldo later makes it to the cathedral in the Royal Capital and successfully changes jobs to Sage, but knows that to get the most out of his magic, he still needs a staff specifically made for Sages.

He visits Mina, who lets him peruse her company's inventory of staffs. He finds one he likes, but it's extremely expensive, and he doesn't have enough money to pay for it, so she offers him a deal; he can have the staff in exchange for his guild membership number. She wants the number so that she can makes requests of him through his guild. It's a great deal for him, as the requests will be optional, and he'll be generously paid for each one he accepts.

He agrees to her deal and is given the staff he wanted. Not long after that, the first request she makes of him is to clear a large field owned by her company of an infestation of monsters referred to as Great Moles. He clears the infestation with ease and heads straight back to Mina, who's amazed at how quickly he completed the request.

[image]

[image]